# A 3-digit integer is chosen randomly. Find the probability that it's possible to add a digit to its right end s.t. the result is a multiple of 45?

Tags: probability

A three-digit integer is chosen at random. What is the probability that it is possible to add a digit to its right end such that the resulting four-digit number is a multiple of $45$?

Edit: I got $\frac{1}{15}$ as my answer can anyone confirm

Comment: Why do you think this is hard ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Well I can’t find a quick way to find 4 digit multiples of 45

Comment: A number is a multiple of 45 if it is a multiple of both 5 and 9. A number is a multiple of 5 if the rightmost digit is 0 or 5. A number is a multiple of 9 if its digits add to a multiple of 9. This means that the 3-digits must add to 9 (so you can add a 0) or add to $9k+4$ so you can add a $5$.

Comment: Hint 45 is divisible by 5 and 9.

Comment: can I use star and bars or something

Comment: By the way, in the future, it would help if you not only said you got such-and-such as an answer, but how you arrived at that answer.  It sounds like more work (and it is, a little), but it helps members of Math SE provide you the most useful answer!

Comment: This is a poorly worded question, relying on the precise but unstated meaning of "three digit" and "four digit" number.  It might be interpreted as asking how many integers $x$ are there in the range $100\le x\le 999$ such that $1000\le x+d \le 9999$ and $45|(x+d)$ for some $d$ with $0\le d \le 9$.

Answer (score 6):

How many 3-digit numbers are there? How many are of the form $9k$? How many are of the form $9k+4$?

For total 3-digit numbers, you have $999-99 = 900$.

For 3-digit numbers of the form $9k$, you have $111-11 = 100$.

For 3-digit numbers of the form $9k+4$, you have $994 = 9k-5 \Longrightarrow k = 111$ and $94 = 9k-5 \Longrightarrow k=11$, so there are $100$ 3-digit numbers of that form.

Total probability: $$\dfrac{200}{900} = \dfrac{2}{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

We have the resulting numbers: $1000,1001,1002,1003,\dots,9999$

This is the sample space (All possible outcomes).

Next, we find out the series of integers that are divisible by $45$: these integers are:

$1035,1080,1126,\dots,9990$

Now, using the a result of arithmetic progression, that the number of terms $n=\frac{\text{last term}-\text{first term}}{\text{common ratio}}+1$

So, $n=\frac{9990-1035}{45}+1=200$

Therefore, the required probability $=\frac{200}{9000}=\frac{2}{90}$

May be I am wrong, I do not believe in $\frac{2}{9}$ as InterstellarProbe answered.

**EDIT (Because I was wrong):**

The $3$-digit numbers that are available: $100,101,102,103,\dots,999$

So a total of $900$ numbers.

Out of these $900$ integers, $200$ integers can be used to create numbers that are divisible by $45$ by adding a digit to the right.

Hence the required probability is $200/900=2/9$

Comment: The problem with this method is you are counting the sample space of 4-digit numbers. But, you are starting with a sample-space of 3-digit numbers. There are only $900$ numbers that are 3-digits. So, your sample space is much too large.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe My English is poor, sorry. Any difference in the following way of asking: "what is the probability that a $4$-digit number is divisible by $45$?". If it is different, please explain to me, would be really appreciated. Thanks InterstellarProbe.

Comment: We aren't choosing a *four*-digit number at random.  We are choosing a *three*-digit number at random.  Having selected a three-digit number, we can then answer the question of if it is possible to append a digit to get a multiple of $45$ or not.

Comment: In your workings, only $4005$ was treated as a "successful" outcome out of $4000,4001,4002,\dots,4009$ with the rest as unsuccessful outcomes but in the actual problem having selected the three-digit number $400$, we are able to say "*yes, if we append the digit $5$ the result $4005$ is indeed a multiple of $45$*" so $400$ was considered a successful outcome.

Comment: "*out of these 900, 200 are divisible by 45*"  No.  $200$ of them have the ability to have a digit appended to them to make the result divisible by $45$.  There are only $20$ numbers between $100$ and $999$ which are divisble by $45$ themselves.

Comment: @JMoravitz you are right, the statement is corrected now, thanks a lot.